# Vue.js : How do I create a form where on submit the input data in the form is added to a table?

Tags: vue.js

I want to create a form where in which the input data is added to a table that is on the next page. With VueJS. 
The form has only a name and a dropdown menu.
I just want to input a name and a selected option to the table from the form.
The data from the dropmenu is - I'm unsure how to pull it into the dropdown.

Here is the [JSON](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1/todos) and my [code](https://codepen.io/asmafayaz1992/pen/LYPxrOe):

Vue.js:

```
new Vue({
   el: "#app",
       data () {
   return {
     loading: false,
     todos: [],
       users_todos:[]
   }
 },

 data:  
 {   
    currentstep: 1,
    steps: [
        {
            id: 1,
            title: "Personal",
            icon_class: "fa fa-user-circle-o"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            title: "Details",
            icon_class: "fa fa-th-list"
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            title: "Send",
            icon_class: "fa fa-paper-plane"
        }
    ]   
 },

 methods: {
     stepChanged(step) {
         this.currentstep = step;
     }  
 },

mounted () {
   this.loading = true;
   axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1/todos?page=1')
   .then(response => {this.users_todos = response.data})
   .catch(error => console.log(error))
   .finally(() => this.loading = false)
}
});
```

Comment: which array you want to add the data to it?

Comment: I want to pull the titles from the array in this URL https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1/todos into a dropdown and then added to a table on submit.

Comment: I want a basic form with a name input and a dropdown menu that contains the titles pulled from the array from this URL jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1/todos and the onclick is the input data is added to a table. I want to be able to delete a row with a confirmation modal and a way of sorting the table